# Update user list .net identity usermanager

Tags: .net, entity-framework-5, asp.net-identity

In mvc 5 project im using identiy. 
and I have user and coupon models,

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{        
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public int AvatarId { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegisterationDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Avatar Avatar { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        this.Coupons = new HashSet<Coupon>();
    }
    public virtual ICollection<Coupon> Coupons { get; set; }
}
```

Coupon

```
public class Coupon
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Barcode { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date{ get; set; }        
    public float Bet { get; set; }
    public Double Price { get; set; }
    public bool System { get; set; }
    public Double TotalGain { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public virtual CouponDetail CouponDetail { get; set; }

}
```

There is a relations between users and coupons.

I want to update User with coupon list by UserManager.

```
private void InsertCoupon(Coupon coupon)
{
    var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    if(userId != null){                
        var user = userManager.FindById(userId);
        user.Coupons.Add(coupon);
        userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
    }

}
```

code works but nothing insert on Coupon table. How can i update user with coupon list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user object returned by this code:

```
var user = userManager.FindById(userId);
```

is a *detached* user. It is not included in the EF context. In order to be able to update an object and you want the changes to be reflected on the database, you should get the user and update it in the same session. Which will give us something like that:

```
if(userId != null){                
    var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId = userId)
    user.Coupons.Add(coupon);
    userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Don't forget to save the changes after the update. With attaching the user object to your context, this should work.

**Using Attach Method**

You can also attach a detached object to your context object. Like this:

```
context.Users.Attach(user);
```

But I would prefer to get the object and update all in the same session like proposed in the first option.

Comment: yes, but UserManager use ApplicationDbContext. check create UserManager instence code line.

Comment: Your UseManager certainly uses ApplicationDbContext to access the database. But it gets the user object in a different session than the one you are using to update the given User. So, you are selecting the user in a session and updating it in an other. If you do this, your update will never work.

Comment: This is a common problem. Just try getting/updating the user object in the same ApplicationDbContext session and with calling SaveChanges() after the update. This will surely work.